# How to create ES5 module as child of parent module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-5

Using ES5 syntax, how do you create sub modules? Why doesn't the following work?

```
// City.js
var City = function(){}
module.exports = City;

// API.js
var City = require('./City');
var API = function(){
  ...
}
API.prototype.City = City;
module.exports = API;

// app.js
var API = require('./API');
var api = new API();

var Orlando = new api.City(); // <--- why doesn't this work?
```

So I have an API module, with a sub/child module "City". When using my API library (which in reality has many more sub-modules besides "City"), I don't want users to have to `require()` every single little sub-module in their `app.js`. I want the API module to do that for them so that all they need to do is instantiate it.

How do I go about doing this? I've seen other types of libraries do this but I'm not sure how. Good example is AWS:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-examples.html

They require the AWS object and then instantiate the `AWS.S3` module. They don't have to `require('S3')` or anything like that.

How do libraries do this?

Comment: Your problem isn't here. What you have here works. Your problem lies elsewhere in the code, and I can't help you without seeing it.

Comment: I've got it to work too. When _you_ say it doesn't work, what's happening exactly? An error? Nothing?

Comment: Hmmm okay I will expand my question. Not sure what is going on. Thanks

Comment: It only works when I do `API.City = City;`. `API.prototype.City = City;` is when it breaks. I get `API.City is not a function` error.

Comment: what is the typeof `City` function?

Comment: When I run your code an empty object is returned.